# When I import Swift, where does it come from?

Tags: swift, import

I am beginning to work my way through Neuburg's iOS Programming with Swift book, and have a real newbie question: Newburg says:

> "your code always implicitly imports Swift itself." (p. 14)

But where does it import it from? Do I need to purchase this "Swift" thing in order to use the Swift language?

Comment: Have you tried to use it? Swift and all its requirements are included with Xcode 6, which you can get off (for free) from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Is means that it imports the `Swift` module/framework by default.